# Rails 4 - Updating an attribute based on time / date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am on Rails 4.

I currently have a `Room` model with an `active?` attribute. When creating a room, users can set different times and dates they want their room to be active.

**My goal**: If a user creates a room with the dates Mar 3 - Mar 5, I would like the `active?` to be set to `true` on Mar 3 and `false` on Mar 5. The same then goes for if the user sets times (ex. 10:00 am - 5:00 pm)

What would be the best way to go about this? Having trouble finding any documentation. Would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: How are you storing your start and end dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear how you are storing your start and end date's, but assuming you have `start_date` and `end_date`, then you could define your `active?` method as follows:

```
def active?
    Date.current >= start_date && Date.current < end_date
end
```

Replace `Date` with `DateTime` if needed

Comment: Yes, I have a `start_date` and `end_date` also being saved to the database. I think this will work, but how would I actually update the `active?` attribute in the database when it reaches the beginning or end of the time?

Comment: You probably don't want to do that, you'd have to have a process that is constantly running and looking for condition to change the database setting. You should calculate if it's active or not unless you have a very compelling reason otherwise.

Comment: you would not have an active attribute in the database, you would solely compute active (or inactive) as above, both in query'ing the db (you can make scopes), and in looking at loaded records. If you really want to have an active column in the db that is updated, you'd need a reoccuring bg job to update it -- which you can do, although there'd always be at least some slight lag where it hadn't been updated properly yet. But this solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reservation table and record the datetime when user make a reservation.

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :reservated_from, :reservated_to
  belongs_to :room
end

class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservation
end
```